# Why is the gerrit change-id commit-hook not a push-hook?

Tags: gerrit

Why is the default gerrit change-id commit-hook not a pre-push-hook?

The default Change-Id "commit-msg"-hook in gerrit adds a Change-Id to every commit. Why is in not implemented as a "pre-push"-hook? If it where it could add Change-Ids only to commits that are pushed to refs/for/...

With the current setup I get Change-Ids in commits that I want to push directly (without a review). It's ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know the answer now.

It would be bad practice for a pre-push hook to change the contents that is being pushed. It could block a push from happening but changing the commits and then automatically precede with the push without the user having a chance to review the changes is bad practice.